# How to prepare android screen independent graphic - specific solution

Tags: android, screen, screen-resolution

Is it possible to use common hdpi folder for all screen densities? I have quite a lot images. If I make specific copies to folders drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-xhdpi, ... but it takes huge data (backgrounds, bitmaps).

Is it possible to set only one drawable folder for all devices and then rescale according to a specific device programmatically?

I think about this code to get display size of the scree:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
width = display.getWidth();
height = display.getHeight();
```

Then I will get display density of the device, something like this:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
density = metrics.density; // 1 - 1,5 - 2 .....
```

The I will recalculate size of imageview with density:

```
ImageView logo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logo);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams logo1 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) logo.getLayoutParams();
logo1.width = (int)(logo.getWidth()*density);
logo1.height = (int)(logo.getHeight()*density);
logo1.leftMargin=(int)(logo1.leftMargin*density);   // for margin
logo1.topMargin=(int)(logo1.topMargin*density);   // for margin
logo1.rightMargin=(int)(logo1.rightMargin*density);   // for margin
logo1.bottomMargin=(int)(logo1.bottomMargin*density);   // for margin
```

My main problem is I need to have all proportions of graphic same on all devices. It means I must recalculate imageViews accroding to the screen size.

Is this a right way to get density independent screen? How does android work on other devices if only hdpi folder contains files. Does it take files from this folder? Can I set one common drawable folder to all densities?

Comment: Only a suggestion: you can also use SVG for some of your images/icons, a sample project here: http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly (***strongly***) advise against doing this. However, if you want the system to rescale your image assets, design them for `mdpi` (the baseline density) and put them in `drawable/`.

That said, you need at least mdpi and hdpi to get reasonable scaling (since hdpi is 1.5x mdpi, scaling algorithms produce worse results than for the other conversions from `mdpi`).

Make sure you've read and understood [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) and [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) before you start dealing with resources.

P.S. The layout solution is wrong for a few reasons (e.g., setting margins instead of size) but it's also the completely wrong thing to do. Don't do it!

Comment: I also strongly advise against this solution. on xxhdpi devices (and yes we are starting to see some of these) your images will be awful.
On mdpi devices, you will use way too much memory since you are manipulating images that are way too big for their screen size and you will expose yourself to out of memory errors.

Comment: Ok, but I need screen to be fully adapted to the device and proportions of graphic to be the same on all devices. If the width of bitmap is 20% on 10" tablet, must be also 20% 10" on 4" mobile phone.  And here I must recalculate ImageView to the actual size of the screen, beacuse every screen has different size (480x320, 1280x800, ...). So this is absolutely wrong way ?

Comment: Making something take 1/5 of the screen is easy with a LinearLayout - just set one weight to 1 and the other to 4. The sizing of Views and ViewGroups has little to do with the sizing of the assets (except that in an ideal world they would always be the same sizes).